# how to read mongodb changestream data by multi process java application ? each process should get unique data

Tags: java

I created a  microservice which is listening to the mongodb changestream notifications  of  a collection (i:e - mycollection) and update the change stream data in another  collection (i;e - yourcollection)

For scalability , I created  10 instance of  my application which will read the same changestream  notifications.

ex -

Suppose at a time  100 records are updated in "mycollection" collections. so change stream will get notification of  the 100 records.

1st instance should  read   1 - 20 records from the changestream and update that records in other collection (i:e - yourcollection)

2nd instance should  update  21 - 40 records from the changestream  and update that records in  collection "yourcollection".

3nd instance should  update  41 - 60 records  from the changestream and update that records in  collection "yourcollection".

so .. on...

no two instance will get same duplicte data from the change stream .

is there any way  to implement the above requirement.

## code snapshot

below are my codes  , each process getting duplicate data.   any suggestion to handle this scenario?

public String startProcess() {

```
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019/user?replSet=simpliReplica"));
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mypoc");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("user");

        try {


            Block<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>> printBlock = new Block<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>>() {
                public void apply(final ChangeStreamDocument<Document> changeStreamDocument) {

                    System.out.println(" MyService:::"+changeStreamDocument.getFullDocument());
                }
            };

            // collection.watch - Establishes a Change Stream on a collection.This will identify any changes happening to the  collection.
            collection.watch(asList(Aggregates.match(Filters.in("operationType", asList("insert", "update", "replace", "delete")))))
            .fullDocument(FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP).forEach(printBlock);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Thannks 
Dillip

Comment: Welcome to SO. We don't write code for you. You need to make an attempt yourself and, if you run into problems, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help on writing a question that will get you help.

Comment: In what scenario would anyone want this? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is define different databases/collections using of:

```
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mypoc");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("user");
```

Then use modulo to iterate over your data and place them into the right collection. For example:

- 21 % 21 = 0.
- 42 % 21 = 0.
- 63 % 21 = 0. etc.